# Why is GDB showing segmentation fault when GCC is compiling and running fine

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am writing a small code to allot space and read and write in it to test the cache monitoring tool. The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define times 2

void write_in_space(int* x, int size){
  printf("\n Entering write in space \n");
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i< size; i++){
    *(x + i) = i;
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n Exiting write_in_space \n");
}

void read_in_space(int* x, int size){

  printf("\n Entering read_in_space \n");
  int i = 0;
  while(i < size){
    *(x + i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n Exiting read_in_space \n");
}

void assign_and_work(int k, int l, int m, int mm){

  printf("\n Entering assign_and_work \n");
  int* space;
  space = (int*)malloc(k * sizeof(int));

  if(mm == 3){
  write_in_space(space , k);
  sleep(m);
  read_in_space(space, l);
}

  else if(mm == 1)
    read_in_space(space, l);

  else if(mm == 2)
    write_in_space(space,k);


  printf("\n Exiting assign_and_work \n");
  free(space);

}

//Driver Code

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int read_space = 0;
  int write_space = 0;
  int sleep_time = 0;
  int i = 1;
  int mode = -1;
  int time = times;
  do{
    if(strcmp(argv[i],"-w") == 0)
      write_space = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    if(strcmp(argv[i],"-r") == 0)
      read_space = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    if(strcmp(argv[i],"-s") == 0)
      sleep_time = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    //if(strcmp(argv[i],"-time") == 0)
      //times = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
    i = i + 1;
  }while( i < argc);

  if(write_space == 0 && read_space > 0)
    mode = 1;
  else if(read_space == 0 && write_space > 0)
    mode = 2;
  else
    mode = 3;

  if((read_space > write_space) && (mode == 3) ){
    write_space = read_space;
  }
    while(time > 0){
    assign_and_work(write_space, read_space, sleep_time, mode);
    time--;
  }


return 0;

}
```

The problem is when I am compiling using the command

```
gcc -o rw readwrite.c
```

and running `./rw -r 500000 -w 800000 -s 20` it is working fine. But when I am trying out using gdb it is showing the following message

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

__strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:31
31  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I am not able to understand the error. I tried using gdb because when I am taking the times as user input through argv it is showing core dumped.

```
 if(strcmp(argv[i],"-time") == 0)
      times = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
```

Please help me understand the fault. I searched a lot but couldn't figure out.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You can use `bt` to get more context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you do not pass arguments to GDB and it fails on line 63 trying to compare non-existing arguments to options. This is a source of failing.

Try using your program without args and see that it fails as well.

If all args are mandatory, you should put an `if` before line 62 to check is number of supplied arguments is right.

Comment: Yes, perfect. that was indeed the mistake. I ran it using gdb --args -r 2000 -w 25000 -s 25 --times 200 and it worked just fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Conclusion: always test `argc`

Comment: @Jabberwocky, good advice, or use the system that can detect null argv like this: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/QdNbKXQ9lkXL35Pt